# How to create objects dynamically during runtime Java

Tags: java, object, dynamic

I'm trying to make a program that is going to need to dynamically create ArrayLists along the lines of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arbitraryInt; i++){
    //code to make 5 new arraylists
}
```

However I can't seem to find any method that would accomplish this.

Edit: I am trying to make a columnar cipher for my APCS class. This cipher requires me to convert a string of any length into a grid. In this case each arraylist would be a column. So to be more specific my code would look somewhat like this:

```
String encode = "somethingsomethingyadayadayada";
int x = 0, y = 0;

for (int i = 0; (i*i) < encode.length(); i++){
    y = i;
    x = i-1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    //make an arraylist
}
```

Is this better @Kartic? I tried to keep it non specific as to keep my post from becoming a code dump.

Comment: Well, where do you want to put them?  What do you want to do with them?

Comment: what's wrong with using `new ArrayList()` 5 times, or in a loop? or having `List<List<Integer>>`?

Comment: In the final version of what I'm trying to make, the number of arraylists will vary depending certain parameters.

Comment: @Sumtinlazy what parameters? please complete your question.. "*along the lines of this*" is not enough

Comment: I got an answer, updated just for you babe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution is to store lists inside list:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arbitraryInt; i++){
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
// get third list
List<Integer> third = listOfLists.get(2);
```